# Where to check who run pipeline in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I need to find info who starts the pipeline (trigered Manual);  In the pipeline runs section there is no info about user only about parent pipeline if applicable (Triggered by column).

I miss something or is this info isn't accessible?

[image]

EDIT:

More specifically, I would like to know who launched a pipeline that has the status "Triggered by" = "Manual Trigger"
[image]

Comment: Is your pipeline published ?

Comment: We can run the pipeline. and Yes it is published.

Answer (score 1):

***Yes***, you are following the process is correct. Checking, who is running the ***pipeline*** in ***Azure Synapse*** but because of the ***RBAC permission*** action issue, you do not have the ***required permission access***.

Please **follow** the below steps to **solve** the **permission issue**:

Open ***synapse studio*** ->***workspace***, expand the **Security section** on the ***left*** and ***select Access control*** -> Add a ***Synapse role assignment.***

[image: Ref1]

[image: Ref2]

> **Check whether your pipelines running or not in azure synapse**

[image: Ref3]

**Reference:**

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-manage-synapse-rbac-role-assignments.md

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-visually

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/synapse-workspace-synapse-rbac-roles

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that's not what I need. Please take a look at my update. I'd like to know who triggered "Manual Triggered"